# Limit Google Maps address lookup to a particular postcode

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do I limit Google Maps address lookup service to street names in a particular postcode or city/town. It is currently giving me all the addresses in the UK, but I would like to limit it to addresses only in Birmingham, UK (B postcode).

**Code so far**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    addressLookup();
});

function addressLookup() {
      var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'uk'
        }
    };
    var address = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control booking address');


    for(var i=0; i< address.length; i++){
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address[i], options);
    }
        //new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address, options);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control booking address" id="pickup" placeholder="From">
<input type="text" class="form-control booking address" id="destination" placeholder="To">
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/45948g02/3/)

Comment: add some logic before you make your call to Autocomplete, preventing it happening if it doesn't start `B`, e.g. `if (address[i].substr(0, 1) !== 'B') ...`

Comment: @duncan - hey not sure I follow 100%, can you please show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the definition of a Birmingham postcode is starts with a B for instance, and I'm assuming each value in the `address` array you're looping over is a postcode (is it?):

```
function isBirmingham(postcode) {
    return postcode.substr(0, 1) === 'B';
}

function addressLookup() {
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {
            country: 'uk'
        }
    };
    var address = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control booking address');

    for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
        if (isBirmingham(address[i])) {
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address[i], options);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

What about setting the `componentRestrictions` in the Autocomplete options?  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions  - the documentation only mentions you can specify a country. However [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/807983/How-to-Geocode-an-Address-by-Postcode-Zipcode-and) demonstrates using a postcode.

Comment: They don't just contain postcodes but actual street addresses. The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45948g02/3/) kinda shows how it works.

Comment: Can you give us a sample address someone might be typing in?

Comment: Off the top of my head its hard to say. `123 Buckingham Palace Road, London, United Kingdom`? They would all be UK based addresses. The issue with the approach you're suggesting is that Google's lookup services (which is what I am using to narrow down the addresses) spits out all kinds of addresses in different format. Hence, I thought it would be a better idea to limit the address list by making a call to the API instead of validating the input box entry.